# Montar tela com dados de array

Tags: php

Tenho um array que é montado pelo https://github.com/RamonSmit/Nestable2
Consegui exibir apenas o `CONTENT` principal (cor vermelho).
Gostaria de saber como faço para exibir o (CONTENT, TIPO PERIODO) [cor azul], abaixo de cada `CONTENT` principal.
Como faço para montar esse foreach da forma correta para exibir os valores acima.

Obrigado.

```
<?php 
foreach (json_decode($row['arrayChecklist'], TRUE) as $ckl) {

    echo $ckl['content']; //Exibe content principal
    foreach(json_decode($row['arrayChecklist'], TRUE) as $ckl2){
        echo $ckl2;
    }
}

echo '<pre>';print_r($ckl);echo '</pre>';
?>
```

.

```
[{"content":"CIVIL","id":1,"children":[{"content":"Verificar e recompor na cobertura, rufos, condutores, tirantes, furacões, executando reforço da impermeabilização nesses pontos","id":2,"tipo":"checkbox","periodo":"Semestral","opt":true},{"content":"Verificar estado geral de portões e grades.","id":3,"tipo":"checkbox","periodo":"Mensal","opt":true},{"content":"Avaliação geral das paredes (quebras, desgaste, pinturas)","id":4,"tipo":"checkbox","periodo":"Mensal","opt":true},{"content":"Verificar estado geral de escadas, corrimões e calçamento efetuando pq reparos (até 5m²)","id":5,"tipo":"checkbox","periodo":"Mensal"},{"content":"Reparos com calafetação de junções em calhas, rufos e condutores.","id":6,"tipo":"checkbox","periodo":"Semestral"},{"content":"Verificar estado geral de conservação de calçadas, pátios, acessos, alambrado.","id":7,"tipo":"checkbox","periodo":"Semestral"},{"content":"Verificar estado de paredes internas, externas e forros efetuando pequenos reparos/pintura (até 20m²).","id":8,"tipo":"checkbox","periodo":"Mensal"},{"content":"Verificar estado de pisos, carpetes e azulejos efetuando pequenos reparos (até 5m²).","id":9,"tipo":"checkbox","periodo":"Mensal"},{"content":"Lubrificação de portões.","id":10,"tipo":"checkbox","periodo":"Mensal"}]},{"content":"INSTALAÇÕES HIDRÁULICAS E PLUVIAIS","id":11,"children":[{"content":"Verificar estado geral de ralos, caixas de gordura e tubulações em geral dos sanitários e copa efetuando os reparos necessários.","id":12,"tipo":"checkbox","periodo":"Mensal","opt":true},{"content":"Verificar dispositivos de acionamento dos vasos sanitários.","id":13,"tipo":"checkbox","periodo":"Mensal"},{"content":"Verificar metais e acessórios defeituosos (sifões, torneiras, válvulas, grelhas de ralo, saboneteiras, espelhos, assentos, engates, etc).","id":14,"tipo":"checkbox","periodo":"Mensal","opt":true},{"content":"Verificação de vazamentos.","id":15,"tipo":"checkbox","periodo":"Mensal"},{"content":"Verificar funcionamento das torneiras e vazamentos dos bebedouros.","id":16,"tipo":"checkbox","periodo":"Mensal"}]},{"content":"INSTALAÇÕES ELÉTRICAS","id":17,"children":[{"content":"Substituir lâmpadas queimadas, soquetes, fotocélulas, reatores, starters, disjuntores, etc","id":18,"tipo":"checkbox","periodo":"Mensal"},{"content":"Luminárias: limpar, verificar fixação, fiação, acrílicos, bocais, vidros de proteção, etc.","id":19,"tipo":"checkbox","periodo":"Mensal"},{"content":"Verificar estado geral de tomadas, interruptores, telefone e cabo de rede, corrigindo eventuais problemas.","id":20,"tipo":"checkbox","periodo":"Mensal"},{"content":"Verificar estado geral de quadros de distribuição e de medição, substituindo elementos defeituosos, verificando fixações, conexões, isolações, aterramento.","id":21,"tipo":"checkbox","periodo":"Mensal","opt":true},{"content":"Relacionar circuitos que estejam com superaquecimento, indicando capacidade do disjuntor, corrente medida a plena carga e bitola do condutor e orçar a correção.","id":22,"tipo":"checkbox","periodo":"Mensal","opt":true},{"content":"Verificar funcionamento, substituir eventuais peças danificadas (lâmpadas, baterias, etc) em luminárias de emergência.","id":23,"tipo":"checkbox","periodo":"Mensal"}]}]
```

IMG `Array`:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o JSON já está decodificado não há nenhum motivo para decodifica-lo novamente.

---

Bastaria usar `$ckl['children'][{index}]['tipo']`. Por exemplo, se quiser pegar sempre o primeiro `tipo` de cada um bastaria trocar o `$ckl['content']` por `$ckl['children']['0']['tipo']`. Obviamente, isto também pode ser feito em outro `foreach`, afim de obter todos os `tipos`:

```
<?php 


// Para visualização:
const SUFIX = PHP_EOL;

// Assumindo que $row['arrayChecklist']  é o JSON:
$row['arrayChecklist'] = '[{"content":"CIVIL","id":1,"children":[{"content":"Verificar e recompor na cobertura, rufos, condutores, tirantes, furacões, executando reforço da impermeabilização nesses pontos","id":2,"tipo":"checkbox","periodo":"Semestral","opt":true},{"content":"Verificar estado geral de portões e grades.","id":3,"tipo":"checkbox","periodo":"Mensal","opt":true},{"content":"Avaliação geral das paredes (quebras, desgaste, pinturas)","id":4,"tipo":"checkbox","periodo":"Mensal","opt":true},{"content":"Verificar estado geral de escadas, corrimões e calçamento efetuando pq reparos (até 5m²)","id":5,"tipo":"checkbox","periodo":"Mensal"},{"content":"Reparos com calafetação de junções em calhas, rufos e condutores.","id":6,"tipo":"checkbox","periodo":"Semestral"},{"content":"Verificar estado geral de conservação de calçadas, pátios, acessos, alambrado.","id":7,"tipo":"checkbox","periodo":"Semestral"},{"content":"Verificar estado de paredes internas, externas e forros efetuando pequenos reparos/pintura (até 20m²).","id":8,"tipo":"checkbox","periodo":"Mensal"},{"content":"Verificar estado de pisos, carpetes e azulejos efetuando pequenos reparos (até 5m²).","id":9,"tipo":"checkbox","periodo":"Mensal"},{"content":"Lubrificação de portões.","id":10,"tipo":"checkbox","periodo":"Mensal"}]},{"content":"INSTALAÇÕES HIDRÁULICAS E PLUVIAIS","id":11,"children":[{"content":"Verificar estado geral de ralos, caixas de gordura e tubulações em geral dos sanitários e copa efetuando os reparos necessários.","id":12,"tipo":"checkbox","periodo":"Mensal","opt":true},{"content":"Verificar dispositivos de acionamento dos vasos sanitários.","id":13,"tipo":"checkbox","periodo":"Mensal"},{"content":"Verificar metais e acessórios defeituosos (sifões, torneiras, válvulas, grelhas de ralo, saboneteiras, espelhos, assentos, engates, etc).","id":14,"tipo":"checkbox","periodo":"Mensal","opt":true},{"content":"Verificação de vazamentos.","id":15,"tipo":"checkbox","periodo":"Mensal"},{"content":"Verificar funcionamento das torneiras e vazamentos dos bebedouros.","id":16,"tipo":"checkbox","periodo":"Mensal"}]},{"content":"INSTALAÇÕES ELÉTRICAS","id":17,"children":[{"content":"Substituir lâmpadas queimadas, soquetes, fotocélulas, reatores, starters, disjuntores, etc","id":18,"tipo":"checkbox","periodo":"Mensal"},{"content":"Luminárias: limpar, verificar fixação, fiação, acrílicos, bocais, vidros de proteção, etc.","id":19,"tipo":"checkbox","periodo":"Mensal"},{"content":"Verificar estado geral de tomadas, interruptores, telefone e cabo de rede, corrigindo eventuais problemas.","id":20,"tipo":"checkbox","periodo":"Mensal"},{"content":"Verificar estado geral de quadros de distribuição e de medição, substituindo elementos defeituosos, verificando fixações, conexões, isolações, aterramento.","id":21,"tipo":"checkbox","periodo":"Mensal","opt":true},{"content":"Relacionar circuitos que estejam com superaquecimento, indicando capacidade do disjuntor, corrente medida a plena carga e bitola do condutor e orçar a correção.","id":22,"tipo":"checkbox","periodo":"Mensal","opt":true},{"content":"Verificar funcionamento, substituir eventuais peças danificadas (lâmpadas, baterias, etc) em luminárias de emergência.","id":23,"tipo":"checkbox","periodo":"Mensal"}]}]';


foreach (json_decode($row['arrayChecklist'], true) as $_ => $val){

    echo $val['content'] . SUFIX;


    foreach($val['children'] as $_ => $val) {
        echo sprintf('[%s] %s' . SUFIX, $val['tipo'], $val['content']);
    }

    echo SUFIX;
}
```

**[Teste aqui.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bc25e05b1e495076513c42b580c4786a2cc7a0db)**